# Entity Framework and generic entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

I have a method:

```
 private static string doGeneric<T>(T DB, string xmlfilename, string headername, string prefix, string xpath)
```

I call it like this:

```
 var res = doGeneric(new cou(), (string)p, "coudata", "cou", "//Cou/Item");
 var res = doGeneric(new ttu(), (string)p, "ttuData", "ttu", "//Ttu/Item");
.
.
.
var res = doGeneric(new xxu(), (string)p, "xxuData", "xxu", "//xxu/Item");
```

`cou()`, `ttu()` and `xxu` are EF entities generated by EF framework (DB first).

In the `doGeneric` method, I have:

```
using (myEFEntity con = new myEFEntity())
```

I want to do something like this:

```
 var cnt = con.DB.Count();
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Did you try writing that code? What happens? Error? `con.DB.count()` what is this by the way?

Comment: @Chetan Ranpariya Compiler error saying DB doesn't exists.  I also tried .T.  That didn't work either.  DB is as part of this `doGeneric<T>(T DB,`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `DbSet` for a given type with the [`DbContext.Set<TEntity>` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696521(v=vs.113).aspx):

> Returns a `DbSet<TEntity>` instance for access to entities of the given type in the context and the underlying store.

In your case, you should be able to dynamically get the count of your `DbSet<T>` by using the following inside `doGeneric<T>`:

```
using (myEFEntity con = new myEFEntity())
{
    var cnt = con.Set<T>().Count();
}
```